# Association is not saved after calling save() on child above

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a problem with saving two-way association.
Having this:

```java
Association association = new Association()
...some data binding
association.save()

Entity entity = new Entity()
entity.addToAssociations(association)
entity.save()
```

If I do this, then in `association` table, `entity_id` is `null` in DB. If I remove `association.save()`, suddenly it works and the `entity_id` is visible.

Do you know where the problem is?

Comment: what do you see in the log?

Comment: the problem is that I don't see anything, it just persists the association without the `entity_id`, but none error thrown

Comment: this is more of a guess but when you do the 2nd option i think you are creating a 1 to 1 association and for the 1st option after saving you need to retrieve from the DB the actual saved association and use that to add to entity

Comment: @Anon this also doesn't help

Comment: You haven't detailed wha save does; Spring doesn't have save methods on entities, so we can't guess at what you've implemented. Save though, from Spring Repository classes, return a managed entity. You are required to use that returned entity going forward, especially when setting references, so that its identity can be maintained. In this case, I would guess that the Entity->Association ref is bidirectional, and has a cascade persist set on it. Since association already was saved, it is a no-op, but since you aren't using the managed instance, the change to Association isn't picked up.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty hard to grasp the context of your problem.
However, I'm going to assume you are using Spring Boot along with Hibernate/JPA.

Considering this, have you set any CascadeType on your association?
I'm going to also assume you are setting the relationship between your entities inside **addToAssociations** method.

You can also have a look at this great article for more information:
https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-hibernate-synchronize-bidirectional-entity-associations/